# Moving data from one html table to another

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am struggling with something that should be so simple.

I am trying to move a row from one html table to another, basically a table with selection options and input to another table with the final selections and values.

[Image for UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GUJo.png)

My Html code is as follow,

```js
function GetIndex()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("table1");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = table.rows[i];
    var createClickHandler = function(row) {
        return function() {
        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        var id = cell.innerHTML;
        console.log("HERE " + id  );

        localStorage.setItem("ID", id);

        
        };
        
    };

    currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    AddNextTable();
    }

}

function AddNextTable()
{

    var ID= localStorage.getItem("ID");
    var table1 = document.getElementById("table1"),
    table2 = document.getElementById("table2");
    

                var table = document.getElementById("table1");
                var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var currentRow = table.rows[i];
                var createClickHandler = function(row) {
                    return function() {
                    var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                    var id = cell.innerHTML;


                var Counter= 0;
                Counter++;
                var InputSelect= "input" + ID;
                console.log(InputSelect);
                var NewText= document.getElementById(InputSelect).value;
                var newRow = table2.insertRow(table2.length),
                    cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
                    cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
                    cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
                    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

                cell1.innerHTML = table1.rows[id].cells[0].innerHTML;
                cell2.innerHTML = table1.rows[id].cells[1].innerHTML;
                cell3.innerHTML = table1.rows[id].cells[2].innerHTML;
                cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='check-tab2'>";

                cell3.innerHTML= "<input type='text' value="+ NewText+ ">"

     
                    
                var index = table1.rows[1].rowIndex;

                    };
                    
                };

                currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
            
                }

}


function tab2_To_tab1()
{
    var table1 = document.getElementById("table1"),
        table2 = document.getElementById("table2"),
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("check-tab2");
console.log("Val1 = " + checkboxes.length);
     for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
         if(checkboxes[i].checked)
            {
                // create new row and cells
                var newRow = table1.insertRow(table1.length),
                    cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
                    cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
                    cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
                    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
                // add values to the cells
                cell1.innerHTML = table2.rows[i+1].cells[0].innerHTML;
                cell2.innerHTML = table2.rows[i+1].cells[1].innerHTML;
                cell3.innerHTML = table2.rows[i+1].cells[2].innerHTML;
                cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='check-tab1'>";
               
                // remove the transfered rows from the second table [table2]
                var index = table2.rows[i+1].rowIndex;
                table2.deleteRow(index);
                // we have deleted some rows so the checkboxes.length have changed
                // so we have to decrement the value of i
                i--;
               console.log(checkboxes.length);
            }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Transfer Rows Between Two HTML Table</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1252">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <style>
            
            .container{overflow: hidden}
            .tab{float: left}
            .tab-btn{margin: 50px;}
            button{display:block;margin-bottom: 20px;}
            tr{transition:all .25s ease-in-out}
            tr:hover{background-color: #ddd;}
            
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="tab">
                <table id="table1" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Mark</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="input1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="GetIndex()">Add</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Dean</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="input2"></td>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="GetIndex()">Add</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Fred</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="input3"></td>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="GetIndex()">Add</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            

            
            <div class="tab">
                <table id="table2" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

My end goal will be for the user to enter a certain amount of an item in the first table, and have it display in the next. I am looping through something incorrectly somewhere.

Comment: What's the checkbox for? Just out of curiosity. Quite strange UI - what are you building?

Comment: `charset="windows-1252"` ? Why not UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it quite complicated about your code. Just why not giving it a param that describes which button/input called the function? It will be much easier and also this will no longer require the use of `localStorage`. Hope this solves your problem.

On the html:

```html
<button onclick="GetIndex('input1')"></button>
```

On the js

```js
function GetIndex(src) {
  ...

  AddIndex(src);
  ...
}

function AddIndex(src) {
  ...

  var ID = src;
  ...
}
```

```js
function GetIndex(src)
{
    var table = document.getElementById("table1");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = table.rows[i];
    var createClickHandler = function(row) {
        return function() {
        var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        var id = cell.innerHTML;
        console.log("HERE " + id  );

        localStorage.setItem("ID", id);

        
        };
        
    };

    currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    AddNextTable(src);
    }

}

function AddNextTable(src)
{

    var table1 = document.getElementById("table1"),
    table2 = document.getElementById("table2");
    

                var table = document.getElementById("table1");
                var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var currentRow = table.rows[i];
                var createClickHandler = function(row) {
                    return function() {
                    var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                    var id = cell.innerHTML;


                var Counter= 0;
                Counter++;
                var InputSelect= src;
                console.log(InputSelect);
                var NewText= document.getElementById(InputSelect).value;
                var newRow = table2.insertRow(table2.length),
                    cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
                    cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
                    cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
                    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

                cell1.innerHTML = table1.rows[id].cells[0].innerHTML;
                cell2.innerHTML = table1.rows[id].cells[1].innerHTML;
                cell3.innerHTML = table1.rows[id].cells[2].innerHTML;
                cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='check-tab2'>";

                cell3.innerHTML= "<input type='text' value="+ NewText+ ">"

     
                    
                var index = table1.rows[1].rowIndex;

                    };
                    
                };

                currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
            
                }

}


function tab2_To_tab1()
{
    var table1 = document.getElementById("table1"),
        table2 = document.getElementById("table2"),
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("check-tab2");
console.log("Val1 = " + checkboxes.length);
     for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
         if(checkboxes[i].checked)
            {
                // create new row and cells
                var newRow = table1.insertRow(table1.length),
                    cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
                    cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1),
                    cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2),
                    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
                // add values to the cells
                cell1.innerHTML = table2.rows[i+1].cells[0].innerHTML;
                cell2.innerHTML = table2.rows[i+1].cells[1].innerHTML;
                cell3.innerHTML = table2.rows[i+1].cells[2].innerHTML;
                cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='check-tab1'>";
               
                // remove the transfered rows from the second table [table2]
                var index = table2.rows[i+1].rowIndex;
                table2.deleteRow(index);
                // we have deleted some rows so the checkboxes.length have changed
                // so we have to decrement the value of i
                i--;
               console.log(checkboxes.length);
            }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Transfer Rows Between Two HTML Table</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1252">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <style>
            
            .container{overflow: hidden}
            .tab{float: left}
            .tab-btn{margin: 50px;}
            button{display:block;margin-bottom: 20px;}
            tr{transition:all .25s ease-in-out}
            tr:hover{background-color: #ddd;}
            
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="tab">
                <table id="table1" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Mark</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="input1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="GetIndex('input1')">Add</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Dean</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="input2"></td>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="GetIndex('input2')">Add</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Fred</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="input3"></td>
                        <td>
                            <button onclick="GetIndex('input3')">Add</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            

            
            <div class="tab">
                <table id="table2" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating.
You don't need localStorage, you don't need almost anything. Just a bit of JS `.append()` to move back and forth your rows. Than using CSS you can additionally pimp the desired items to show/hide or even the button text:

```js
const moveTR = (ev) => {
  const EL_tr = ev.currentTarget.closest("tr");
  const sel = EL_tr.closest("table").id === "table1" ? "#table2" : "#table1";
  document.querySelector(sel + " tbody").append(EL_tr);
};

document.querySelectorAll("table button")
  .forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", moveTR));
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td {border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px 10px;}

#table1 button::after {content: "Add"}
#table2 button::after {content: "\2715"}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>Amount</th><th>Action</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td><td>Fred</td><td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td><td>Dean</td><td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>Mark</td><td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><button type="button"></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>Amount</th><th>Action</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```